# Aligning LSB of two arrays into columns in C

Tags: c, arrays, alignment, multiple-columns

I have two arrays of decimals with the same number of indexes in each. How can I right-align the LSB in each column like this?:

```
 359230595  10
1746442051   8
1170647010   8
 202212421   7
 800051251   7
1112147574   8
1135948848   8
   3367006   5
3869426816   7
```

Either using printf, or even better would be getting each line into a string array so I can output it to another .txt file more easily.

Comment: Have you tried anything? (Maybe **reading the documentation?**)

Comment: Yeah, I tried using a function to figure out the longest number in each array, then figure out the number of digits for each, then add spaces depending on the difference from the max. This seems like a really round-about way though. Isn't there something more simple?

Comment: This does not look like binary, so there is no LSbit (and certainly no LSByte either). You mean right-alignment of integer values? Show your code and read the manpage of `printf`.

Comment: If you tried that, add this bit of (very relevant and important) detail to the question. Include that code as well. Then explain what problem this leaves you with.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll delete this question and start reading about printf although I don't see how a printf in a loop is going to know the lengths of the iterations that came before or after it..

Comment: It won't. That doesn't change the fact you need to modify your question (no need to delete it *yet*)

Comment: The code I wrote isn't done so I didn't see the point. Last time I posted unfinished code someone told me I was missing a semi-colon and to create a new question if there was other issues. Basically before spending another 2-3 hours going in the wrong direction I wanted to see if there was a better way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel confident that this has been asked and answered before.  To make it easy on you, however...

`printf` has an alignment operation that you can use.  You can find it if you read the manual page.  For example:

```
 printf("%*d %*d\n", 10, x, 10, y);
```

Note that the `*` has been inserted where you would typically find a precision marker.  The `*` is used as a placeholder for you to indicate the maximum length for that field.  In this case, this will produce two right-aligned columns 10 spaces in width, separated by one space.

Comment: Thanks I tried to search first maybe I wasn't using the right keywords

Comment: @Austin Note: You can alternatively use `printf("%10d %10d\n", x, y);` if it's always 10. (Either one will work)